# Nodejs basics: How and where I can use require(module)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have just started playing with nodeJs. At the moment I have such project:

Structure:
- app.js
- response.js

app.js code:

```
var callback = require('./response.js');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

// body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// test route
app.get('/', function (req, res) { res.status(200).send('Hello world!') });

app.post('/test', callback);

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(400).send(err.message);
});

app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Slack bot listening on port ' + port);
});
```

My response.js is:

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  return res.status(200).json({
    attachments: [{ "test": "test" }})]
  });
}
```

As you can see here I'm using express server to listen for post requests to /test endpoint and responding to those with some test json.

**Question:** I want to use mongo - to get same data from database and return it with the response when /test endpoint is triggered. Mongodb tutorials directs me to install mongodb npm module and then to include mongodb module and do the rest for example like this:

```
// Retrieve
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

// Connect to the db
MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/exampleDb", function(err, db) {
  if(!err) {
    console.log("We are connected");
  }
});
```

- Can I require for mongodb (require('mongodb')) in response.js? If yes should it be inside the function or outside module.exports ?
- If I require('mongodb') in app.js is there a way to use it in response.js?

Comment: Yes, you can require mongodb in response.js and it should be outside exports. If you require mongodb in app.js, you will not be able to use it in response.js

Comment: Thanks Sky, if you will add this as proper answer I will select is as right one.

Comment: I have added it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can require mongodb in response.js and it should be outside exports. If you require mongodb in app.js, you will not be able to use it in response.js

Answer (score 1):

You can require in each module whatever you want.
use require only outside from all scopes(Not in function) as it sync method and will block your server.
Also it's ok to require same module in multiple other modules. node js knows not to recompile it.

Hope it was helpful.

Comment: itai, thanks for the answer bus Sky answered it first in comments, so I have accepted his answer anyway, thank you!